# ISC-DHCP server assigning two IP addresses to the same interface?

Tags: isc-dhcpd

I have ISC DHCP server on a RaspberryPi (called VPNbridge) with two Ethernet devices. One is ordinary (internal) Ethernet device (`eth0`), the other is USB-to-Ethernet device (`eth1`) to which I have connected Aastra VoIP phone. So RaspberryPi server as a "bridge" for Aastra VoIP phone to the VPN network.

The problem is, that Aastra phone (or any other device connected to that interface on RaspberryPi) is loosing connectivity every couple of minutes. Also, `eth1` device on RaspberryPi has two IP addresses.

Here is my config:

In `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` I have:

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

ddns-update-style none;

authoritative;
subnet 192.168.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.100.50 192.168.100.51;
  option routers 192.168.100.1;
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
  option domain-name "vpnbridge.local";
  ###option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
}

host aastraphone {
  hardware ethernet 00:08:5d:35:e8:57;
  fixed-address 192.168.100.51;
}
```

In `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` I have:

```
INTERFACESv4="eth1"
INTERFACESv6=""
```

`sudo systemctl status isc-dhcp-server`

```
● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-08-06 23:37:59 CEST; 4min 42s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 597 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2059)
   CGroup: /system.slice/isc-dhcp-server.service
           └─671 /usr/sbin/dhcpd -4 -q -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf eth1

avg 06 23:41:44 vpnbridge dhcpd[671]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:e0:4c:89:c3:e2 via eth1
avg 06 23:41:45 vpnbridge dhcpd[671]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.100.50 to 00:e0:4c:89:c3:e2 (vpnbridge) via eth1
avg 06 23:41:45 vpnbridge dhcpd[671]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.100.50 (192.168.100.1) from 00:e0:4c:89:c3:e2 (vpnbridge) via eth1
avg 06 23:41:45 vpnbridge dhcpd[671]: DHCPACK on 192.168.100.50 to 00:e0:4c:89:c3:e2 (vpnbridge) via eth1
avg 06 23:41:48 vpnbridge dhcpd[671]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:08:5d:35:e8:57 via eth1
avg 06 23:41:48 vpnbridge dhcpd[671]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.100.51 to 00:08:5d:35:e8:57 via eth1
avg 06 23:41:50 vpnbridge dhcpd[671]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:08:5d:35:e8:57 via eth1
avg 06 23:41:50 vpnbridge dhcpd[671]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.100.51 to 00:08:5d:35:e8:57 via eth1
avg 06 23:41:55 vpnbridge dhcpd[671]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.100.51 (192.168.100.1) from 00:08:5d:35:e8:57 via eth1
avg 06 23:41:55 vpnbridge dhcpd[671]: DHCPACK on 192.168.100.51 to 00:08:5d:35:e8:57 via eth1
```

`ip a show eth1` on RaspberryPi shows:

```
5: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:89:c3:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.100.50/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global secondary dynamic noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft 474sec preferred_lft 399sec
    inet6 fe80::2e0:4cff:fe89:c3e2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Also, on a RaspberryPi I have:
`cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth1`:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.100.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @thrig In Debian-style `/etc/network/interfaces` (or `interfaces.d` files), `auto eth1` means just "start interface eth1 on boot", nothing else. It has nothing to do with DHCP.

Comment: Yes, I know, but still, why ISC-DHCP assigns IP address to `eth1` if it has already assigned IP and is in fact interface ISC-DHCP server should be listening to...?

Comment: Also, I noticed this in logs today:
`avg 07 09:07:49 vpnbridge dhcpd[6403]: Dynamic and static leases present for 192.168.100.51.
avg 07 09:07:49 vpnbridge dhcpd[6403]: Remove host declaration aastraphone or remove 192.168.100.51
avg 07 09:07:49 vpnbridge dhcpd[6403]: from the dynamic address pool for 192.168.100.0/24`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your system has not one but *two* DHCP components:

- `dhcpd`, the ISC DHCP *server*
- `dhcpcd`, Roy Marples's DHCP *client*, or `dhclient` the ISC DHCP *client*

You are trying to use Debian-style `/etc/network/interfaces`, but modern versions of RasPiOS have moved away from that: it still sort of works since RasPiOS is based on Debian and they've wanted to keep backward compatibility.

But the preferred way in current RasPiOS is to use the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file (the DHCP *client* configuration file, note the second "C") for all network interface configuration, including static IP assignments(!). You may want to read the official RasPiOS documentation on network configuration: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#using-the-command-line

Doing it that way might make dealing with hot-plugged USB network adapters a bit simpler, so that might be why RasPiOS has chosen that method.

If you want to use `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth1` for configuring `eth1`, then you'll at least need to add `denyinterfaces eth1` to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to tell the DHCP client to not assign a dynamic address to `eth1`.

Regarding the log message you mentioned in the comments:

```
dhcpd[6403]: Dynamic and static leases present for 192.168.100.51. avg 07 09:07:49 vpnbridge dhcpd[6403]: Remove host declaration aastraphone or remove 192.168.100.51 avg 07 09:07:49 vpnbridge dhcpd[6403]: from the dynamic address pool for 192.168.100.0/24
```

The `range 192.168.100.50 192.168.100.51;` in your `subnet` declaration in the DHCP server configuration says that the addresses ...50 and ...51 are for dynamic assigment to any valid client who asks; the static assignments (using `host` declarations) should not use any addresses within the `range` statement, and vice versa.

If your intent is to only provide static DHCP for specific VoIP phone(s) or other devices whose hardware addresses are known in advance, then you might remove or comment out the `range` statement altogether.

Comment: Thanks, it seems this solved my problem - I included static IP assignment for `eth1` in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file (the DHCP client configuration file) and now VoIP phone is keeping connection for more than two hours. I will see how stable is everything after a day or two, but it seems the problem is solved. Many thanks!